# Android application with SSL

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate, self-signed

I know that this particular topic was asked many times, but unfortunately in my case none of them are working. For past few days I was trying to get it to functional state, but I failed every time, so I finally come here to ask.

I have a webservice on server with self-signed certificate. I can access wsdl file if I enter address into browser. Browser just remind me, that there is some issues with cert. and if I hit continue, everything works. Sadly I know very little about SSL, because its first time I made an application with SSL communication. In application I'll only get exception "No peer certificate" or "Trust anchor path not found" depends on type of "solution" I used.

I ran test on sslhopper.com and I get a warning that "The certificate is not trusted in all web browsers. You may need to install an Intermediate/chain certificate to link it to a trusted root certificate." Is this a serious issue in Android development or it could be resolved by some code?

So my question is actually, how can I do in application make "hit the continue button" or anything to make it actually connected to the server. In this case is it problem with certificate itself or am I doing something wrong on the application itself?

Comment: What have you tried and how is it not working for you? Generally you have to create keystore file with your certificate and use a custom TrustStore based on that in your app. Also what APIs are you using to do HTTP (HttpClient, URLConnection, something else)?

Comment: I tried it with httpClient. At this point, I tried many solutions but none of them work. Even when I load the bks file, it told me exception with "no peer certificate". I really don't know what to do. Funny thing is, that on iOS I have zero problem to get it to work, but Android version of the app is needed too : (

Comment: You really need to describe what you have done more clearly if you expect any help. Post code, certificates, Android version(s) tested, etc. You can also read this for some perspective: http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2011/12/using-custom-certificate-trust-store-on.html

Comment: Oh, its your work : ) I'll tried your sample app, few days back. I checked "Set javax.net.ssl.trustStore" and when i pressed "HttpClient SSLSocketFactory Connect" I've got the "no peer certificate error" and when I pressed "HttpsURLConnection Connect" I've got a "Trusted anchor path not found" error. I suspect, that there is some error with cert. I have no experience with SSL connection on Android or SSL connection in general. Would that been helpful if I posted certification info from OpenSSL? I am sorry if I sound dumb. Many thanks for your comments.

Comment: You don't sound dumb but you really need to provide more details. Did you manage to import the certificate? On what Android version, etc. See above.

Comment: I am trying it on Android 2.2 emulator. I actually don't own a Android handset. Client require working version from Android 2.2<. I've got a certificate in pfx format, which I convert to bks keystore in Protecle. Everything was done without any errors, so I assume, that I succeeded in this step. That I added to app package. In case of your application I guess that is working fine, because when I mistyped password its throws an error (keystore integrity check failed). Is it even possible to connect on froyo without certicate signed with proper trusted CA?

Comment: Here is information about the certificate: http://pastebin.com/xnrPLXFu

Comment: Are you trying to perform client authentication? Did you install the CA certificate in the trust store? It is not possible to connect without trusting the issuer CA, so you have to add its certificate to either the system or the application trust store.

Comment: No, I am simply trying to connect. We are using SSL, just for secure connection. User authentication is done by login/password. I was trying to add certificate to trust store by using solution with Bouncy Castle trusto store. But that doesn't seems to work. What bothers me, that I can access the page by Android standard browser, only thing that I need to do, is click on "continue" when prompt with "problem with certificate" appears. Server side there isn't any client authentication, but even with "allow all host name" I still getting same error. "No peer certificate".

Comment: I am trying to play with OpenSSL a trying to understand whats wrong and I managed to got a "no peer certificate" error, by connection to the site with port 80. But in my app, I have set a schema for https connection with port 443. Is there possibility, that this schema is ignored? I feel like I tried everything. Worst thing that using custom certificates is requied by client, who want me to develop the application. At this point, I would probably just buy a commercial certificate...but I can't : (

Comment: You have to connect to 443 in order for the SSL code to be executed. If you are trying to do client authentication, you need two things: 1. the CA certificate that issued the server certificate 2. a client certificate for your app. You have to put 1. in the trust store and 2. in the keystore for your app. The sample code expects a PCKS#12 as the keystore, do you have one? What files have you been given? At this point it might be good to read the JSSE reference so you have an idea how the system works. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html

Comment: Now we actually getting somewhere, I've been given one *.pfx file which I assumed is some kind of certificate file. So at this point I assume, that only change pfx to bks file isn't enough... Can I extract information from pfx file to act like trustore and keystore at the same time, or I need some extra files? Thank you in advance

Comment: I finally managed to connect! I dump certificate directly from the server, saved it as a bks and it works. Thank you so much, without your help, I wouldn't be able to do it.

Comment: That is one way to do it, but, unless the server certificate is self-signed, you should really put the CA certificate in the trust store. In your case may this is the 'CN=AMI Computers Certification Authority'. Also adding my previous comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to do client authentication, you need two things:

1. the CA certificate that issued the server certificate
2. a client certificate for your app.

You have to put 1. in the trust store and 2. in the keystore for your app. The sample code expects a PCKS#12 as the keystore, do you have one? What files have you been given? At this point it might be good to read the JSSE reference so you have an idea how the system works:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html

Comment: I managed to connect with all your great comments, so thank you very much one more time. I flag this answer as answered, so in this case I have not any additional questions. Have a nice day : )