# Android Application for money handling

Tags: android, ssl, banking

I am planing to create a android application for doing some banking operations like fund transfer and all, but I fear the security of the application. Doing some research I found that `"128-bit SSL protection"` is the best way to protect mobile application. But I dont know any thing about that 128-bit SSL protection. Can any one tell me how I can implement this? and what are the other perfect ways to ensure the security of the transactions. Please give your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement SSL(HTTPS) to your App.

You need to follow this doc : http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html

Also,i hope this may help :

[Android application with SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12840558/android-application-with-ssl)

Comment: thank-you for the quick response and i will check this, in the mean time can i ask you that do you have any experience in banking apps.

Comment: yes i had worked for a bank for around 2 years ...did a bit of RnD on 2-way SSL and kind-of even implemented it too for the web interface ... just follow the links i have provided you will surely get leads to how to go about doing it ...